React filter arrays using PaginatedList
I'm filtering a list of users from my DB according to their names. It works fine.
Now I added react-paginated-list for a better list view but I'm stuck in how to filter that list again listing users even if their names are not on that page.
export function Users() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [active, setActive] = useState("");

    const [users, setUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [openUsersList, setOpenUsersList] = useState(false);


    const handleFilterByUser = (e: any) => {
        setUser(e.target.value);
    }

return (

//...

// drop down menu 

<div className="mt-12 w-full">
   <p className='text-sm'>Filter</p>
   <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center sm:justify-start gap-2 mt-4 w-full">
      <select className='border border-zinc-300 p-2' onChange={(e) =>
         handleFilterByUser(e)}>
         <option value="" key={0}>Filter by name</option>
         {usersList.concat(users).sort((a: any, b: any) => a.username.localeCompare(b.username)).map((user: any, index: any) => (
         <option key={index} value={user.username}>{user.username}</option>
         ))}
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

  <PaginatedList
    list={users}
    itemsPerPage={10}
    renderList={(list) => (

  <div className="flex flex-col justify-center sm:justify-start mt-12 w-full">
    {openUsersList && list.filter((userVal) => {

        if (user === "" && active === "") {
            return userVal;
        } else {
            if (user !== "" && userVal.username.toLowerCase().includes(user.toLowerCase())) {
                return userVal
            }
            if (active !== "" && userVal.active.toLowerCase().includes(active.toLowerCase())) {
                return userVal
            }
        }
    }).map((user, index) => (

        <div key={index} className="flex flex-wrap justify-center sm:justify-start border border-zinc-300 mt-6 w-full">

             <div className="flex items-center w-5/6 h-full p-2 sm:pl-6">
                 <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
                     <p className='text-blue-900 text-xs uppercase hover:underline cursor-pointer' onClick={() => openUser(user.id)}>
                         <strong>{user.username}</strong>
                     </p>
                     <p className='text-zinc-500 text-xs mt-1'>
                         <a href={"mailto:" + user.email}>
                             {user.email}
                         </a>
                     </p>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    ))
    </div>
 )}
 />

I read some questions about filtering two arrays but it didn't work.
Edit
Let's consider I'm listing page 2, when I apply the filter, selecting a user on a drop down menu, if that user is not on page 2, it doesn't display any user. I would like to display any user filtered by my drop down menu, even if they are not listed on specific page.

Can you further explain what is not working, and your expected result? Demo

@YongShun ok. Please check my edit and missing code
